# Controller is not called in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I want to pass params from one view to another. In my index.html.erb I have an empty div:

**index.html.erb:**

```
<div id="main"> </div>
```

First I am loading the main.html.erb file within a side bar by the following link:

**side.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to image_tag('btn_next.png'), home_main_path(:game_id=>item.game.id), :remote => true %>
```

This is loading my main.html.erb file into the main-div. Here is some code:

**main.js.erb**

```
$("#main").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'home/main.html.erb', :handlers => [:erb]) %>");
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
def main
    puts 'main called'
    ...
```

**logs**

```
main called


Started GET "/home/main?game_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-15 18:54:37 +0100
Processing by HomeController#main as JS
  Parameters: {"game_id"=>"1"}
```

Everything works fine. Now, inside the the main.html.erb I have a link to a game_main.html.erb file:

**main.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to I18n.t('basic.game_statistic'), home_game_main_path(:game_id => @game.id, :mode => 'GameGoals'), :remote => true, :class => "main" %>
```

Here some code for the game_main link:

**game_main.js.erb**

```
$("#main").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'home/game_main.html.erb', :handlers => [:erb]) %>");
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
def game_main
    puts 'game_main called'
    ...
```

The html file gets loaded inside the main-div. But the game_main-controller is not called. My logs:

**logs**

```
Started GET "/home/game_main?game_id=1&mode=GameGoals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-15 19:13:19 +0100
Processing by HomeController#game_main as JS
  Parameters: {"game_id"=>"1", "mode"=>"GameGoals"}
```

without a notice 'game_main called'. So I am not able to get the params. What went wrong? I am able to process the HomeController#main but not HomeController#game_main.

Thanks for help.

Lars

P.S.: My routes:

**routes.rb**

```
match '/home/main', :to => 'home#main' 
match '/home/game_main', :to => 'home#game_main'
```

**rake routes**

```
home_main        /home/main(.:format)                  home#main
home_game_main   /home/game_main(.:format)             home#game_main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer and actually it was my mistake. In my home_controller I defined the game_main action twice. I deleted one action and it worked.

Conclusion:

1. An action inside a controller won't be called if it is defined twice.
2. You don't get an error message if you define an action inside a controller twice.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using

> render

```
$("#main").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'home/game_main.html.erb', :handlers => [:erb]) %>");
```

Rendering a view file won't execute any method. You need to explicitly call that method in your link_to hyperlink.

Comment: But it worked with the main.html.erb file?! Any suggestions how to code this?

Comment: I tried t with <%= link_to I18n.t('basic.game_statistic'), home_game_main_path(:game_id => @game.id, :mode => 'GameGoals'), method: :get, :controller => :home_controller, :action => :game_main, :remote => true, :class => "main" %> - not working